# Create a generic function that takes in a view controller type as a parameter and returns a custom view controller based on that type

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm trying to create a generic function that takes in a view controller type as a parameter and returns a custom view controller based on that type.

```
func setUpInstance<T>(_ viewControllerType: T, toName: String?) -> T where T: UIViewController {

        switch viewControllerType {

            case  is GetInstructionsModalViewController:
               let getInstructionsVC = getViewController(GetInstructionsModalViewController.self, "Instructions", identifier: "GetInstructionsVC")
                     getInstructionsVC.delegate = self
                     getInstructionsVC.getDirectionsDelegate = self
                     getInstructionsVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
                     moveButtonsAccordingToViewHeight(getInstructionsVC.height)

                 return getInstructionsVC as! T

           case is TurnModalViewController:
                let turnVC = getViewController(TurnModalViewController.self, "Turns", identifier: "TurnVC")
                    turnVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
                    turnVC.delegate = self
                    turnVC.toName = toName
                    bottomContainer.isHidden = true
                    moveButtonsAccordingToViewHeight(turnVC.height)
               return turnVC as! T

           default:
                return UIViewController.self as! T
            }

        }
```

when I try and instantiate the custom view controller:

```
let turnVC = setUpInstance(TurnModalViewController, toName: nil)
```

I get an error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'TurnByTurnModalViewController.Type' to
>   expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Any idea on how to make this function do its job properly?

Comment: You seem to have written a similar function to this already. Look at how `getViewController` is written, and see how its signature is different from yours.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes I did, but I tried it that way too but it wasnt working properly: func getViewController<T>(_ viewControllerType: T.Type, _ name: String, identifier: String) -> T where T: UIViewController {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: name, bundle: nil)
        let identifier = String(describing: identifier)
        return storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! T
    }

Comment: @Sweeper there was an error I don't have at the moment

Comment: And what was the error message?

Comment: @Sweeper its on my other computer at the moment, i think the answer given though should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you mixed up how to use generics. 
First of all, you need to change the signature of the function to

`func setUpInstance<T>(_ viewControllerType: T.Type, toName: String?) -> T where T: UIViewController`

since you'd like to check the input type and return the instance of that type

then call it with the right parameter

`let turnVC = setUpInstance(TurnModalViewController.self, toName: nil)`

Comment: and don't forget to change the default case to something like `return UIViewController() as! T`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example how to use ViewController as Generic type

```
func viewController<T: UIViewController>(_ controller: T.Type) -> T {
   let storyBoardId = (controller as UIViewController.Type).storyboardId
   return instance.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyBoardId) as! T
  }
```

so your function will be like this

```
func setUpInstance<T: UIViewController>(_ viewControllerType: T, toName: String?) -> T where T: UIViewController {

        switch viewControllerType {

            case  is GetInstructionsModalViewController:
               let getInstructionsVC = getViewController(GetInstructionsModalViewController.self, "Instructions", identifier: "GetInstructionsVC")
                     getInstructionsVC.delegate = self
                     getInstructionsVC.getDirectionsDelegate = self
                     getInstructionsVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
                     moveButtonsAccordingToViewHeight(getInstructionsVC.height)

                 return getInstructionsVC as! T

           case is TurnModalViewController:
                let turnVC = getViewController(TurnModalViewController.self, "Turns", identifier: "TurnVC")
                    turnVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
                    turnVC.delegate = self
                    turnVC.toName = toName
                    bottomContainer.isHidden = true
                    moveButtonsAccordingToViewHeight(turnVC.height)
               return turnVC as! T

           default:
                return UIViewController.self as! T
            }

        }
```